# Set a separate file as home page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've noticed there are a lot of similar posts, but can't seem to sift through the pile for the right one.

I'm creating a custom theme. I have a separate file, "foo.php", that I want to be the un-editable homepage or front page of the the site.

Then, I want to use a different file/template for the rest of the site.

How do I do this?

Comment: if ypu have not add your comment in template name so simply your file give a name front-page.php  see the http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very top of the `foo.php` template, insert the following code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home Page Template
*/
?>
```

In WordPress, create a page called "Home" (or really, whatever you like).  You don't need to add any content using the editor if it's all in the `foo.php` file.  To the right of the editor you'll see a dropdown that lets you choose a template - pick the one you just created, "Home Page Template".

Last, go to the "Reading" section of the WordPress dashboard and set your newly created page, "Home" as a **static front page**.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, but it does not quite answer my question. Those drop downs only allow me to select pages that I create, which aren't physical files. I have "foo.php" and "bar.php". I want the former to be my home page template, and the latter to server as the template for the posts/pages.

Comment: It does answer your question - you are associating the "physical" file foo.php when you assign it as a template while editing a "non-physical" page in WordPress. If you want to have a template used for posts and pages, replace the contents of single.php (for posts) and page.php (for pages).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a new file and name it `home.php`, and you can use any WordPress parameters in there. This file will automatically take over your `index.php`, and it will be displayed as your homepage.

From the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy):

1. WordPress first determines whether it has a static front page. If a static front page has been set, then WordPress loads that page according to the page template hierarchy.
2. If a static front page has not been set, then WordPress looks for a template file called home.php and uses it to generate the requested page.
3. If `home.php` is missing, WordPress looks for a file called `index.php` in the active theme's directory, and uses that template to generate the page.

You can either create a static front page by going to Reading settings in your dashboard, or using the first method.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: And then all subsequent pages will use index.php?

Comment: No, they will use `home.php`.

Comment: Ok, well I want to use a static page for the home page, and all subsequent calls use a different file.

Comment: @Josh: See the updated answer. Hopefully that answers your question!

Comment: Thanks for your patience, but it does not quite answer my question. Those drop downs only allow me to select pages that I create, which aren't physical files. I have "foo.php" and "bar.php". I want the former to be my home page template, and the latter to server as the template for the posts/pages.